# File fields and columns adjustment with awk [LINUX]

Tags: regex, linux, shell, delimiter

I have an issue with columns delimiters adjustment in a file in linux into a database.

I need 14 columns and I use **"|"** as a delimiter so I applied :

```
awk -F'|' '{missing=14-NF;if(missing==0){print $0}else{printf "%s",$0;for(i=1;i<=missing-1;i++){printf "|"};print "|"}}' myFile
```

Suppose I have a row like that:

```
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i|
```

after applying the awk command it will be:

```
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i||
```

and this is not acceptable I need the data to be 14 columns only.

Sample input {In case of 14 fields row]:

```
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i
```

Do nothing

Sample input {In case of extra fields]:

```
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i|
```

ouput:

```
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i
```

Sample Input {In case of less fields}:

```
a|b|c|d||e||f||g|h
```

output:

```
a|b|c|d||e||f||g|h|||
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do mention your sample of expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: Kindly update your question, comments are NOT meant for codes/samples, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v n=14 '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
{
   $0 = gensub(/^(([^|]*\|){13}[^|]*)\|.*/, "\\1", "1")
   for (i=NF+1; i<=n; ++i)
      $i = ""
} 1' file

a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i
a|b|c|d||e||f||g|h|||
```

Where original file is this:

```bash
cat file

a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i
a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i|
a|b|c|d||e||f||g|h
```

Here:

- Using `gnsub` we remove all extra fields
- Using `for` loop we create new fields to make `NF = n`

---

If you don't have `gnu-awk` then following should work on non-gnu awk (tested on BSD awk):

```bash
awk -v n=14 '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
{
   for (i=NF+1; i<=n; ++i) $i=""
   for (i=n+1; i<=NF; ++i) $i=""
   NF = n
} 1' file
```

Comment: Hi, this shall work if NF=14 or less.. but in case of an extra delimiter, it will delete the last delimiter and the last value. please check the output for extra fields again

Comment: Out of 3 lines shown in my generated output which one is not matching your expected output?

Comment: The second output... input: a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i| ---> output: a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|   It should be a|b|c|d|e||f||g||||h|i

Comment: ok got it. I have updated my answer now. It matches with your expected output.